# How to load angular1 dependencies using systemjs?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs

I'm using **typescript**, **angular1** and **systemjs** in the following example.

The problem that I have is I'm not able to load the dependencies for the module **app** as in

```
module('app', ["ngComponentRouter", "hub"])
```

I see an error in the chrome dev tab that the injecting a module failed.

The **System.import** loads the app module which supposed to load the **hub** module also. But how to inject the **hub** module as a dependency for **app** module?

**index.html**

```
<app></app>

<script src="~/lib/system.js/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script>
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        baseURL: "wwwroot",
        map: {
            "angular": "/lib/angular/angular.min.js",
            "hub": "/App/hub.js"
        }
    });
    System.import('./App/app');
</script>
```

**app.ts**

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as hub from './hub/hub'

module App {
    "use strict";

    export class AppController {

        static $inject = [
            "$router"
        ];

        constructor(private $router: any) {
            $router.config([
                { path: "/hub", component: "hub", as: "Hub" },
                { path: "/home", component: "home", as: "Home" }
            ]);

            $router.navigateByUrl("hub");
        }

    }

    angular.
        module('app', ["ngComponentRouter", "hub"]).
        controller('AppController', AppController).
        directive('app', () => {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                template: "<ng-outlet><ng-outlet>",
                controller: "AppController"
            }
        });
}
```

**hub.ts**

```
export module Hub {

    export class Tile {
        title: string;
        name: string;

        constructor(title: string, name: string) {
            this.name = name;
            this.title = title;
        }
    }

    export class HubController {

        selectedTiles: number[];
        hubTiles: Tile[];

        static $inject = [
            "$scope",
            "$router"
        ];

        constructor(private $scope: any, private $router: any) {

            this.hubTiles = [new Tile("USA", "home"),
                new Tile("Canada", "home"),
                new Tile("Mexico", ""),
                new Tile("India", ""),
                new Tile("Germany", ""),
                new Tile("Australia", "")];

            this.selectedTiles = [];

            $scope.$watch(() => this.selectedTiles, (newValue: number[], oldValue: number[]) => {

                if (newValue[0] != oldValue[0]) {
                    $router.navigateByUrl(this.hubTiles[newValue[0]].name);
                }

            }, true);
        }
    }

    var hub = angular.
        module("hub", ["ngComponentRouter", "winjs"]).
        controller("HubController", HubController).
        directive("hub", () => {
            return {
                templateUrl: "./app/hub/hub.html",
                controller: HubController,
                controllerAs: "hub"
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I am struggling this for almost a week..
skeleton repo : https://github.com/AmirSasson/Angular1TypescriptSystemJs
 everything is fine till I need my App module to be dependent on other ng dependency such as ngRoute

Comment: No. I moved myself to angular2.

Comment: good for you!
I wish I could to migrate as well.
I have managed to solve it somehow eventually.
https://github.com/AmirSasson/Angular1TypescriptSystemJs